# sort list with negative numbers

Tags: python

I'm trying to sort a list without modifying the existing list or by using built in functions like `sort` or `sorted`. I am having trouble when encountering negative numbers. For example sorting the list

```
[7,1,-5,18]
```

produces

```
[1, -5, 7, 18]
```

instead of

```
[-5, 1, 7, 18]
```

My code:

```
lst = [7,1,-5,18]
b = list()
init = lst[0]
for i in range(len(lst)):
    b.append(lst[i])
    if b[i]<init:
        tmp = init
        b[i-1] = b[i]
        b[i] = tmp

print b
```

Comment: Does it sort `[2,1,0,3]` correctly? You've jumped to a conclusion (your program doesn't work if the list contains negative numbers) that isn't warranted.

Comment: Since the best method of sorting are `O(logn)` and it is not bucket sorting it seems not to be possible to sort list in one loop iteration so there is for sure something wrong with your code. What alghoritm do you want to use?

Comment: @m.antkowicz A sorting algorithm operating in `O(log n)` time? I don't think so. ;-) In order to sort a sequence on `n` elements, you should look at each element at least once to tell where it goes, so you can't possibly be better than `O(n)` (and indeed, there are such algorithms, e.g. counting sort).

Comment: @FrerichRaabe - yup you're right I meant O(n*logn) for QuickSort for example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this selection sort logic:

```
>>> l=[7,1,-5,18]
>>> for i in range(len(l)):
...     for j in range(i+1, len(l)):
...         if l[j]<l[i]:
...             l[i],l[j]=l[j], l[i]
... 
>>> l
[-5, 1, 7, 18]
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that you're appending values to the end of the list, then moving them *one* position to the left if they're smaller than the previous element. After changing the position of an element in the list, you would have to check if it needs to be moved *again*.

Step by step, this is what happens:

```
remaining elements to sort | "sorted" list | what happens
7,1,-5,18                    []              
1,-5,18                      [7]             first element enters the sorted list
-5,18                        [7,1]           2nd element enters the sorted list
-5,18                        [1,7]           7>1, so last element changes location
18                           [1,7,-5]        3rd element enters sorted list
18                           [1,-5,7]        7>-5, last element changes location
[]                           [1,-5,7,18]     instead of checking whether 1>-5, the 4th
                                             element enters the list
```

This can easily be fixed by changing the `if` to a loop like so:

```
lst = [7,1,-5,18]
b = list()
for i in range(len(lst)):
    b.append(lst[i])
    while i>0 and b[i]<b[i-1]:
        b[i], b[i-1] = b[i-1], b[i]
        i-= 1

print b
```